# Проблема с сокетом java + as3

Tags: java, сокет, actionscript-3

Проблема заключается в том, что если с сервера отправить несколько сообщений сразу, то на клиенте это все превратится в кашу и слушатель сокета ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA сработает только один раз. Вот код Java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
String msg = "test msg";
ss = new ServerSocket(12345);

while(true){
    s = ss.accept();
    s.setTcpNoDelay(true);
    for(int i = 0; i< 10;i++){
      send(msg,s);
    }
  }
}

public static synchronized void send(String msg,Socket sender) throws IOException{
   OutputStream os = sender.getOutputStream();
   os.write(msg.getBytes(), 0, msg.length());
   os.flush();
}
```

AS3:

```
var socket:Socket = new Socket();
    socket.connect("127.0.0.1", 12345);
    socket.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, function():void{
        trace("conneted");
    });
    socket.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, function(e:Event):void{
        var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        var size:int = socket.bytesAvailable;
        socket.readBytes(bytes, 0, size)
        var a:String = bytes.readUTFBytes(size);
        trace("что то пришло: " + a);
    });
```

Вот что произошло в логах клиента:

"что то пришло: test msgtest msgtest msgtest msgtest msgtest msgtest msgtest msgtest msgtest msg"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Здесь нету каши. Сокет - это двусторонний канал передачи данных. Все байты отправленные в сокет посредством `send` в том же порядке будут получены принимающей стороной. Отправка и получение данных не имеют никаких границ.

Пример:
Отправляющая сторона отправляет два набора данных, каждый по 8 байт: "aaaabbbb", "ccccdddd".

1. Принимающая сторона может получить два набора данных "aaaabbbb" и "ccccdddd". Этого можно добиться если отправляющая сторона сделает небольшую паузу после отправки первого набора данных.
2. Более вероятный вариант - придет один набор данных 
   "aaaabbbbccccdddd" - если между `send` пауз не было.
3. Также возможна любая другая комбинация. В крайнем случае обработчик получения данных на принимающей стороне может сработать хоть 16 раз, каждый раз получая ровно 1 байт.

В общем случае оправку и получение данных следует понимать как непрерывный поток. Из этого следует что необходимо самостоятельно разработать протокол обмена данными который бы решал задачу разбивки данных на сообщения. Это легко сделать представив сообщение как пару Заголовок и Тело. Простейший заголовок обязан иметь хотя-бы одно поле - длину сообщения. Дополнительно можно внести еще одно поле - тип сообщения. Ваши сообщения можно представить так:

```
{
  length: длина сообщения, с заголовком или без, по вкусу
  type: тип сообщения
  body: "test msg"
}
```

Это пример текстового протокола. Таким же образом можно реализовать бинарный протокол. В самом простом случае, если протокол основан на текстовых командах можно ограничиться простым ограничителем строк. Это может быть нуль символ, или любой другой неиспользуемый символ. Для примера возьмем символ "|". Тогда отправленные данные надо снабжать этим разделителем. Получающая сторона в итоге (помним что данные приходят порциями) получит
`"test msg|test msg|test msg|test msg|test m"` 
Я намеренно оборвал поток, потому что в реальности так и будет. Принимающая же сторона обязана парсить этот поток. То-есть считывать байты до тех пор пока не встретим разделитель, это сигнализирует что полностью прочитана очередная команда. Конец сообщения демонстрирует возможность не встретить ограничитель. В этом случае данные необходимо сохранить и ждать следующую порцию данных, например - `"sgtest msg|test msg|"` 
Аналогично поступаем с протоколом основанном на заголовке.

1. Убеждаемся что накоплено данных соответствующих длине заголовка (тут бинарный протокол удобнее, так как заголовок имеет фиксированную длину). Если нет ждем следующую порцию данных.
2. Убеждаемся что накопллено данных соответствующих телу сообщения. Если нет ждем следующую порцию данных.